# how can I implement iterable for LinkedList<LinkedList<obj>>

Tags: java, linked-list, iterable

I have created :

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<Object>>
```

I know how to implement `Iterable` for regular linked list in order to iterate.

However, how can I implement `Iterable` in order to be able to iterate over my collection when it is

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<Object>> ?
```

Comment: Do you mean an `Iterator`? A `LinkedList`, like any other collection, already implements `Iterable`.

Comment: I have a class that one of her members is a LinkedList<LinkedList<SomeObject>> and this class need to implement the interface iterable..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Iterable` is a generic interface. Since you want to iterate over a `LinkedList<LinkedList<Object>>`, you can implement the interface with the type parameter set to `LinkedList<Object>`.

**Sample runnable class:**

```
public class IterableClass implements Iterable<LinkedList<Object>>{
    LinkedList<LinkedList <Object>> l = new LinkedList<LinkedList<Object>>();


    public IterableClass() {
        super();
        LinkedList<Object> a = new LinkedList<Object>();
        a.add("a1");
        a.add("a2");
        LinkedList<Object> b = new LinkedList<Object>();
        b.add("b1");
        b.add("b2");
        l.add(a);
        l.add(b);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IterableClass iterableObject = new IterableClass();
        for(Iterator<LinkedList<Object>> it = iterableObject.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            LinkedList<Object> list = it.next();
            for (Iterator<Object> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                Object object = iterator.next();
                System.out.println(object);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<LinkedList<Object>> iterator() {
        return l.iterator();
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
a1
a2
b1
b2
```

Answer (score 1):

Like here:

```
Iterator<LinkedList <Object>> iterator = yourList.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    LinkedList<Object> embededList=iterator.next();
    Iterator<Object> embededIterator= embededList.iterator();
    while(embededIterator.hasNext()){
       System.out.println(embededIterator.next());
    }
}
```

**edited.**

Comment: what will be the return value of the function iterator? will it be iterator <LinkedList <object>> or iterator LinkedList<LinkedList<object>>?

Comment: yeah, it will be Iterator<LinkedList <Object>>